# Can a function be declared as a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, javascript-objects, object-properties

Consider the following JavaScript object definition :

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function() {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};
```

I know that if we want to use the object property(i.e. a function) we have to write the following code :

```
person.fullName();
```

As per my knowledge, JavaScript objects are containers for named values called properties or methods.

Also, I know that I can define the object properties like **firstName, lastName, id** as individual variables.
Now, my question is can I also define the function "fullName" as a variable? If it is possible then how? and if not then why?

Thank You.

Comment: There are several ways to do what you're asking. See this question for other options for declaring a function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: Have you tried `var fullName = function() { ... }`? You can then call `fullName()`. Note that then within the function `this.firstName` wouldn't work unless `firstName` is a global variable.

Comment: A function is also just a value like any other value and can be treated the same way.

Comment: I think OP meant `variable` as if a property can be defined dynamically or have a function property be accessed without the call, I'm not sure about it though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Note that your code is equivalent to this code:

```
var person = {};
person.firstName = "John";
person.lastName = "Doe";
person.id = 5566;
person.fullName = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

The important bit to see is that `function() { return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }` (or rather, the result of evaluation of that string of code) is a *value*, just like `5566` is, and can be contained in a property, or a variable, or an array... just like `5566` can. The only difference is, one is a number, the other - a function.

Besides the original example of a function stored in a property ("method"), here is an example of a functional value being stored in a variable:

```
var sayHello = function(name) { console.log("Hello, " + name); }
```

Here it is in an array:

```
var adders = [
  function(x) { return a; },
  function(x) { return (a + 1) % 3; }
  function(x) { return (a + 2) % 3; }
];
```

Here it is being passed as a parameter:

```
function twice(f, x) {
  return f(f(x));
}
twice(function(x) { return x * 2; }, 7);
// 28
```

Comment: This is still defining the function as a property. Doesn't the OP mean `var fullName = function() {}`?

Comment: @nnnnnn I'll rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

Here is simple answer with example to your question

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    window.$ = jQuery;
    initializeGlobelCalls.init();   
});

var initializeGlobelCalls = function () {
    var validatefunction = function() {
        $(document).on('click','#divid',function(){//event trigger when you want to call function
        //your function code
        });
    };
return {
        init: function () {
          validatefuction();//can add multiple functions here
        }
       };
 }();
```

with this structure you can write multiple functions ,first need to define function like `validatefunction` and then add into init

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript a variable can point to function as well.

Example:

```
var fullName = function(param) {
  return param;
}

console. log(fullName('some text'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you generate `fullName` when creating the object such as the following:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : ''
};
person.fullName = person.firstName + person.lastName;
```

Otherwise there's no way to create a **static** variable only one that will be created by the function when called (such as in your original example).
That is not possible because by the way JavaScript was designed, you can't have dynamic properties assigned statically (apart from ES6 getters as cited below, which will still generate the value on **every** call) in a way that they'll only be generated once automatically without some kind of algorithm from your part or a library to do that for you.

As I cited above, you can try [ES6 getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) but that will only make it *look like* a property, it will still get called **every time** it is accessed:

Example:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    get fullName() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }
};
```

Then you'd access it like this: `person.fullName`